# Hiding div using "visibility:hidden" on IOS devices

Tags: jquery, html, ios, touch, visibility

I've been using some code which is working to my liking across all browsers and devices except the Ipad and Iphone. The issue is that I'm not sure how to implement a touch event where by tapping off the selected div it is then hidden.

```
<body>
<div id="main_nav">
<ul id="nav">
<li class="nav">
<a href="#" onmouseout="mclosetime()" onmouseover="mopen('m1')">
<span class="nav_parent">CONTACT</span></a> 
<div id="m1"
onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()"
onmouseout="mclosetime()">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>  
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>
</li></ul></div>
</body>
```

---

```
var timeout = 50;
var closetimer = 10;
var ddmenuitem = 0;
// open hidden layer
function mopen(id) {
    // cancel close timer
    mcancelclosetime();
    // get new layer and show it
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
// close showed layer
function mclose() {
    if (ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
// go close timer
function mclosetime() {
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}
// cancel close timer
function mcancelclosetime() {
    if (closetimer) {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
}}
document.onclick = mclose;
// close layer when click-out
```

Below is a fiddle to demonstrate what I have. As mentioned, I realize that I am using mouseover events which work as expected across desktop browsers and even on android devices. I'm just looking for a method to close the opened sub menu div when I tap elsewhere on the screen (css is posted in fiddle).

https://jsfiddle.net/t859A/28/

edit

I added the following code which succeeds in closing the submenu when the document is touched however it also closes when a link is touched within the menu.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function mclose(){
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}, false)
}, false)
```

Is there some way to remove the even listener from the menu as shown in my example fiddle?

Thanks

Comment: Do you consider to use jQuery  for cross browser functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a flag when the menu is open.  And, then you can have a touch event handler on the `document` object (since touch events bubble up the DOM tree).  Then anytime you get a touch event on the `document` object event handler, you check for two things: 1) is the menu open and 2) is the touch event outside of the menu?  If so, you close the menu.  If not, you ignore the touch event and let it's normal processing handle it.

If, when the menu is open, you need to prevent default behavior for touch events outside the menu, then you might need to do a bit more work, either with a capture when the menu opens or with a transparent div below the menu, but over the rest of the window that intercepts that outside touch event so it isn't processed by anything else.

Comment: Can you provide a link on how this could be accomplished? Specifically maintaining a flag when the menu is open?

Comment: What can I say? life gets busy... I have posted all the relevant code along with a fiddle above. I don't know how to be more specific. I got stuck trying to close the menu on IOS devices as shown in my fiddle. I was thinking that because of your general answer you may have a source to point me to in order to help me understand how to accomplish the above. In any event I always return to my questions in hopes of solving them and marking correct answers.